# How to evaluate this definite integral? $\int_0^{0.5\ln3}\tfrac1{e^x+e^{-x}}dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> By using the substitution $u=e^x$, determine the value of:
>   $$\int_0^{\tfrac12\ln3}\cfrac1{e^x+e^{-x}}\mathrm dx.$$

I've made the substitution and I'm already stuck... What's the next step?

Comment: What did you get after the substitution?  Write it as a rational function of $u$.

Comment: further to @GEdgar comment: $$
\int \frac{\mathrm{e}^{x}}{1+\mathrm{e}^{2x}}dx
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $u=e^x$. Then $du = e^x\,dx$ so $\displaystyle dx=\frac{du}{u}$. Moreover,
\begin{align*}
 u(0) &= 1 & u\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln(3)\right) &= \sqrt3
\end{align*}
It follows that
$$
\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}\ln(3)}\frac{dx}{e^x+e^{-x}}=\int_1^{\sqrt3}\frac{1}{u+u^{-1}}\frac{1}{u}\,du
$$
Can you finish the integration?